# Close Events after using it in WaitForMultipleObjects function

Tags: c++, winapi, events

I have a vector of event objects, which is used in `WaitForMultipleObjects` function. After an event is signalled I tried to close the event using the close handle function, but I am getting an error like `Invalid handle was specified`. Can anybody tell that what the issue is?

```
std::vector<HANDLE> eventVector;
//..
// Entering data to vector

size_t count = eventVector.size();
DWORD signaledEvent;
While(count > 0)
{
  if (WAIT_OBJECT_0 == (signaledEvent =     WaitForMultipleObjects(handleVector.size(),handleVector.data(), false, INFINITE)))
  CloseHandle(handleVector[signaledEvent - WAIT_OBJECT_0]); // Here I am getting error.
  count--;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On the first iteration it possibly worked out well, but then once you close the handle, you cannot supply the same vector to `WaitForMultipleObjects` once again: at least one of the handles is no longer valid.

So `WaitForMultipleObjects` returns you an error there, and possibly another one later in `CloseHandle`.

This is not your real code, right? Because in this code snippet you don't really check returned values for errors. Because this code snippet has more errors to note:

- if(...); - empty conditional block
- because of the one above you might be accessing vector with illegal index
- you check `WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 0` only, and not other `WAIT_OBJECT_0 + N`

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer. But while running this code I am getting error in the 1st iteration itself. after removing the close handle it works fine. And yes, this is not my real code, its a sample only. But I am not checking the error values in the real code too.

Comment: Thanks for adding more information on this. But I didn't get those points you mentioned in the last paragraph. Where is this empty conditional block? I checked the values(index values for vectors) and verified that the indexes are correct. And here, I have to check only the WAIT_OBJECT_0, for knowing that any events in the eventVector is set.

Comment: `1` remove last semicolon from if line `2` you have to compare "if(<result> - WAIT_OBJECT_0 < eventVector.size()" because `WAIT_OBJECT_0 + N` is still a valid return value.

Comment: ok. I agree with this. Sorry for the misplacing the semi colon. Otherwise, i think my code is ok. bocs after removing the close handle it works fine